# How to Read text filled in a Text Box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here I am Providing u the Text Box Image with its X-path

[image: Click Here]

and Here is the Code for it, that I had tried:

```
{
    String NameTxtBxData = driver.findelement(By.id("ngoName")).gettext();
    System.out.println(NameTxtBxData);
}
```

Comment: i think, the name entered manually by user...right?

Comment: yes noor It is a profile page and at the time of SignUp this data was entered

Comment: if this data is enter by user, than u can not get it through ur code. Because this is not ur html page property.

Comment: Ok noor so is there any other methods to get text from it. I mean some thing like Cut copy paste, or can we do it using Remote class

Answer (score 0):

The element with id "ngoName" is an input. The text from an input is defined in the `value` property/attribute:

```
String NameTxtBxData = driver.findElement(By.id("ngoName")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to read a value form a text filed or any input filed there is a hidden attribute **value** which keeps the value entered by you inside it hence to read the value in the text box simply do it like below

```
String NameTxtBxData = driver.findelement(By.id("ngoName")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(NameTxtBxData);
```

Hope this helps you